# I install Zulu Open Source JDK Java 8 212 but it installs as 8 191. Why?

Tags: windows-10, installation, java

I've tried installing this on Windows 10 Enterprise. It's advertised as 212, the most recent. When I do, it installs 191 and an update notification comes up and links to Oracle. We don't want to use the enterprise version and have to pay for that when the open source is available. I've tried this from Azul (Zulu) and from [openjdk.java.net](https://openjdk.java.net).

Answer (score -1):

So I put in a support email to Azul and they responded back saying they weren't aware of the issue and they are investigating it.